# Launch Google app with search query from intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I was wondering how to launch the google search app with a search query from an intent. All my searches for an answer have resulted in a way to open the browser and search Google but I would like to open the actual app for the search. Thanks in advance

Comment: I want to achieve the exact same thing, sad that noone had a solution to this :(